# Spark Package on Docker Container

Tags: java, apache-spark, docker

I am working on building a Dockerized spark cluster that will connect to HBase.  I would like to use the [Hortonwork shc package](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc) to manage the connection.  I can get the package included by using the `--packages` flag with the necessary `--repository` flag (the plugin is not in the sbt).

This works fine, but re-downloads the package every time the container is restarted. Non-ideal.

Where does the `--packages` flag on a spark submit download the jars and dependencies?  Taking a snapshot after downloading did not work and I suspect it is because I need to add the jar using --classpath.

Comment: You could just make an uber jar with all the needed dependencies and run that.

Comment: Otherwise `$SPARK_HOME/jars` would be a good place to look

Comment: Create a "lib" folder in a project directory and place all compiled jars there. Spark will load those jars as unmanaged dependencies. You can also specify jars using --jars parameter in spark-submit

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies can be specified at deployment time of spark operator using "packages:" https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/user-guide.md#specifying-deployment-mode